# R - making emdash among negative values when labelling discrete bins

Tags: r, legend, symbols, bins, discrete

I'm cutting a dataframe `shp` into discrete bins, some of which are negative values. I'm wondering how I can make an em dash in between negative values (e.g. "0 - -2.5") for the labels to appear more readable in the legend when plotting?

`shp <- shp %>% mutate(discrete_var = cut(mean, c(-0.4,-0.10,-0.5,-0.025,0,0.05,0.1,0.15,4), labels = c("-10 -","-5 - -10","-2.5 - -5","0 - -2.5","0-5","5-10", "10-15","15-")))`

[image]

Comment: uh an em dash is `—`. What you have is `- -`. Replace one with the other and you should be good to go?

Comment: If you want an easy way to create an em dash, use `"\u2014"`. For example `"-10 \u2014 0"` gives `"-10 — 0"`

Comment: I think though that it is better to substitute the em dash for the word "to", i.e. `"-10 to -5"` - that's much less ambiguous.

Comment: Also, note that the equivalent of `0-5` would be `-2.5 - 0` - i.e. the lower / most-negative number first.

Comment: Thanks! "\u2014" works, as @AllanCameron suggested.

Comment: And yes, the other formatting suggestions are also good advice, thanks @PaulStaffordAllen.